# FullCalendar dayGrid View does not show view options in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, fullcalendar-3

I am using FullCalendar v5 in JS
When I try to use dayGrid View, it is not working.

Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output]

Output Received:
[image: Output Received]
I have added a script tag at the top of my PHP file for the dayGrid plugin:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@5.9.0/"></script>
```

The following script tag is used to add the buttons on the header:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            initialView: 'dayGridWeek',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridDay,dayGridWeek'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the jQuery-based syntax you've used, you appear to be using fullCalendar v3 (or below), not v5. (v4 and above are not implemented as jQuery plugins and the syntax to initialise the calendar is quite different.)

Therefore you need to refer to the documentation here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc

Once you do that, you'll see that

a) the view names are all different, and

b) the option for setting the view at startup is `defaultView`, not `initialView`.

Therefore the code you would need is:

```
var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  defaultView: "agendaWeek",
  header: {
    left: "prev,next",
    center: "title",
    right: "month,agendaDay,agendaWeek"
  },
  editable: true,
  events: "https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json"
});
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWgpaao

P.S. The link `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@5.9.0/` is just a link to one of the plugin files for version 5.9, it's not the main fullCalendar file. If you're managing to get a calendar working using v3 then you don't need that reference at all.

Comment: Is there a way to use JQuery with FullCalendar v5?

Comment: Well you can't use jQuery to initialise the calendar (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals for instructions on initialising a v5 calendar), but there's nothing stopping you from continuing to use it for anything else in your code. What specifically do you want to use it for?